# Show hidden div by typing div name/title into search form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is show a hidden div by typing a word into a search form. The div contains a single image. All divs are hidden by default, so it has to un-hide the div...

Example: The div has title="robot", and has an image of a robot in it. I type "robot" into search form and the script (oninput?) searches for div with title="robot" and shows div/image.

I am new to scripting/jquery and cannot seem to figure it out, any help is much appreciated! Here is code I found and tried to get to work, but it does not...

```
<div id="div1" class="div">
<img class="robot" id="robot" src="robot.jpg" title="robot" style="display:none"></a>
</div>

<form class="pure-form">
<legend></legend>
<input type="text" placeholder="Example: robot" class="pure-input-rounded"     onkeyup="showDiv(this.value)">
<button type="button" name="answer" class="pure-button">Search</button>
</form>

<script>
function showDiv(value) {
if (value.charAt(value.length - 1) == ' ')
document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "block";
else 
document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<div id="noresults" style="display:none" class="results" >No such thing...</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery solution

html

```
<div class="cardContainer hidden robot">
   <img src="robot.jpg" title="robot" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="cardContainer hidden human">
   <img src="human.jpg" title="human" alt="" />
</div>

<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Example: robot" class="pure-input-rounded">
</form>

<div id="noResults" class="hidden">no results</div>
```

css

```
.hidden
{
  display:none;
}
```

js

```
$(".pure-input-rounded").on("keyup", function()
{
  var value = $(this).val();

  if($("." + value).length)
  {
    $(".cardContainer").hide();
    $("." + value).show();   
    $("#noResults").hide();
  }
  else
    {
       $("#noResults").show();
       $(".cardContainer").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm... I understood it easily, and it's snappy. to All Thank you for such quick replies :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
function showDiv(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
       $("#noresults").show()
    } 
    else {
       $("#noresults").hide()
    }
}
```

The value would be the passed length of the text in the text box

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
<script>
function showDiv(value) {
    if (value.length > 0)
        document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "block";
    else 
        document.getElementById('noresults').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using JQuery mostly, makes for better/cleaner code imho:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //ensures events are added after the DOM is loaded..
  function showDiv(value) {
     if (value == ' ') {
         $('#noresults').show(); // same as setting style = display: block;
    }
    else {
       $('#noresults').hide(); //same as setting style = display: none;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //If you want the image appear on the keyup event
    $('.pure-input-rounded').on('keyup',function(){
        var t=$('.pure-input-rounded').val()
        if(t==='robot'){
            $('#div1 img').show()
            };
        });
    //If you want the image appear on form submit you have to change the input type button/submit
    $('.pure-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var t=$('.pure-input-rounded').val()
        if(t==='robot'){
            $('#div1 img').show()
            };
        });
})
```